# While making build in Cordova using cmd

Tags: cordova, cmd, android-build

While making build using Cordova by cdm it is sending this error

**Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  **

Please Suggest solution.

Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced similar issue after upgrading to Cordova 6.4.0 from Cordova 6.2.0. Managed to resolve it by adding **`_JAVA_OPTIONS`** variable with value **`-Xmx512M`** in system variables available under environment variables.

Screenshot as follows:

[image: Making variable in user defined]

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Create Variable with name
(_JAVA_OPTIONS)
Value = -Xmx512M
(_JAVA_OPTIONS)
(Your Path of JDK bin folder)
Simple as follow.

Comment: Yes, Little bit changes is order to make it workable.
Please check my comment.
Thankyou

Comment: Thank you for making it easy for me, i have did some edits so that it can more easily understandable.
Regards

Comment: @SHH java bin path should be set in path system variable not in java options variable... That's what I have in my environment to make it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131922/discussion-between-shh-and-gandhi).