# ionic cordova build android fails

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am trying to run ionic cordova build android but its failing with below error:

> PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\recipe> ionic cordova build android ? The
>   Ionic CLI (local version) has an update available (3.7.0 => 3.9.2)!
>   Would you like to install it? No [INFO] Not automatically updating
>   your CLI. You can update manually:
>
> ```
>    npm install --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest
> ```
>
> Running app-scripts build: --build --iscordovaserve --nobrowser
>
> [00:09:37]  build dev started ... [00:09:37]  clean started ...
>   [00:09:37]  clean finished in 12 ms [00:09:37]  copy started ...
>   [00:09:37]  transpile started ... [00:09:43]  transpile finished in
>   5.09 s [00:09:43]  preprocess started ... [00:09:43]  deeplinks started ... [00:09:43]  deeplinks finished in 127 ms [00:09:43] 
>   preprocess finished in 129 ms [00:09:43]  webpack started ...
>   [00:09:44]  copy finished in 6.24 s [00:09:59]  webpack finished in
>   15.82 s [00:09:59]  sass started ... [00:10:02]  sass finished in 3.59 s [00:10:02]  postprocess started ... [00:10:02]  postprocess finished
>   in 7 ms [00:10:02]  lint started ... [00:10:02]  build dev finished in
>   24.82 s
>
> > ionic cordova prepare
> >     cordova prepare | Running command [00:10:09]  tslint: C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/recipe/src/pages/shopping-list/shopping-list.ts,
> >     line: 2
> >                 All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { IngredientService } from "../../service/shopping-list";
> ```
>
> [00:10:09]  tslint:
>   C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/recipe/src/pages/edit-recipe/edit-recipe.ts,
>   line: 3
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController, AlertController, ToastController } from
> ```
>
> 'ionic-angular' ;
>          L3:  import { Recipe } from "../../models/Recipe";
>          L4:  import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from "@angular/forms";
>
> [00:10:09]  tslint:
>   C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/recipe/src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts, line: 2
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { ShoppingListPage } from "../shopping-list/shopping-list";
> ```
>
> [00:10:09]  lint finished in 6.88 s √ Running command - done!
>
> You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova
>   telemetry on.
>
> > cordova build android × Running command - failed!
>
> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit
>   code 1):
>
> ```
>     You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
>     ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>     JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_144
>     Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>     Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>     * What went wrong:
>     Unable to start the daemon process.
>     This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>     For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>     Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>     Please read the following process output to find out more:
>     -----------------------
>     Error occurred during initialization of VM
>     Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
>
>
>     * Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>     Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>     * What went wrong:
>     Unable to start the daemon process.
>     This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>     For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>     Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>     Please read the following process output to find out more:
>     -----------------------
>     Error occurred during initialization of VM
>     Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
>
>
>     * Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> ```

And this is what I get on running ionic info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\recipe\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
    @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.2
    OS   : Windows 10
    npm  : 5.3.0
```

I have android studio already installed and I did build an app before this one. Why do I get error on this one. Can someone asssist.

Comment: `You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.`. Did you try running `cordova build android` ?

Comment: @AakashThakur Check out my answer in the following link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394419/while-making-build-in-cordova-using-cmd This should do