# ionic cordova could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to To generate a release build for Android, but after command: "ionic cordova build --release android" I've got the exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
(node:7276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
(node:7276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

*I tried this:*
Go to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced(tab) -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New:
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M
GRADLE_OPTS : -Xmx2048M
*And this:* So You must have the Android Api 23 in order for this command to work.
Error of Daemon process will be solve after installing the Api 23 and extra 
build tools and run command 
*I've loaded* last version of jdk/jre(64-bit)
 *I tried* to make a gradle.properties with this:org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
But this exception still occures. Please, help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer in the [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394419/while-making-build-in-cordova-using-cmd/41394914#41394914). You can set _JAVA_OPTIONS in system variables available under environment variables.

An other option is to switch from 32-bit JDK to 64-bit JDK. Hope it helps

Comment: As I wrote, I've already tried this ways: tried this: 1._JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xmx512M                                                                       
        2.GRADLE_OPTS : -Xmx2048M                                                      
 3. Android Api 23                                                                                
  4.last version of jdk/jre(64-bit)                                                                 5. gradle.properties with this:org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: @fel sorry i overlooked it. Which version of cordova?

Comment: Node version: v8.9.4  Cordova version: 8.0.0

Comment: @fel do you have any plugins added to it? did u removed and added android platform after cordova update?

Comment: Yes. Switching to 64-bit JDK worked for me too. Similar thread, with similar solutions can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216921/cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-2097152kb-object-heap